# Coroutines Parent job is Cancelled Exception

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I was running a simple *Retrofit* request with `Coroutine launch` and got this error `kotlinx.coroutines.JobCancellationException: Parent job is Cancelled; job=JobImpl{Cancelled}@759d1e0`

The request works in the first attempt and returns exception on a second.

Here is my class:

```
class QuestionPresenter(
    private val uiContext: CoroutineContext,
    private val view: QuestionView
): BasePresenter(uiContext, view) {

    val service = ApiServiceImpl()

    fun getSendQuestionResponse(email: String, text: String) {

        view.showProgressIndicator(true)

        val job = launch(coroutineContext) {
            val data = service.getRetrofit().getSendQuestionResponse()
            if (data != null) {
                view.getSendQuestionResponse(true)
            }
        }.invokeOnCompletion {
            it?.let {
                view.showError(it)
            }
            view.showProgressIndicator(false)
        }
    }

}
```

And code to build coroutine context:

```
private val job = Job()

private val exceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, throwable ->
    baseView.showError(throwable)
}

override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
    get() = mainContext + job + exceptionHandler
```

Please give me some advice on what is wrong

Comment: Use a `SupervisorJob` instead. Your code means that the first coroutine error prevents any future coroutines from starting.

Comment: It is also worth pointing out that `viewModelScope` uses a `SupervisorJob` by default. I would argue that `BasePresenter` should extend `ViewModel`. If you do, you should re architect `BasePresenter` so it does not hold a reference to the `View`

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Thanks, it helped. I am wondering why I can not use normal Job instead and why first coroutine error is generated.

Comment: @Emmanuel I was experimenting with architectures. This one is classic MVP and I did not use ViewModel. But it is nice to know that ViewModel has this feature.

Comment: The "normal" `Job` is used for scoped job hierarchies where all the jobs must be cancelled if any job fails. `SupervisorJob` is used in your case, where child jobs are allowed to fail.